# Device token changes each time when registered for push notification in iOS 9.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios9.3.1

I have an app which is working fine in iOS versions upto 9.2.1. The in these os versions the device token received is same as till the app is reinstalled.
But after updating the iPhone to iOS 9.3.1 I am starting to get different push token each time when I unregister and register again. Just before login register for push is called and when the user logout unregister is called.
Is this any new changes in iOS 9.3.1 or I am getting this issue because of some other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form of this phase of token trust ensures that only APNs generates the token which it will later honor, and it can assure itself that a token handed to it by a device is the same token that it previously provisioned for that particular device—and only for that device.

If the user restores backup data to a new device or reinstalls the operating system, the device token changes.

i every time you  registered for push notification device token will regenrated some time it return same some time different . you can not reliable on device token.